# Use an inital dataset with Select2 and only send Ajax search when user Types chacters

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select2 box.

```
   <%= f.select :key_pole_id,
      @span.decorate.key_poles_to_search,
      {:include_blank => true},
      class: 'key-pole-search' %>
```

Which I initialise like this:

```
  $('.key-pole-search').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",        
    ajax: {
      url: '/key_poles/search',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,      
    }
  });
```

Which works, except the intital values set never get displayed.  When the user clicks into the Select2 search box, an ajax request is triggered with an empty search term, which repopulates the list with other poles.

I'd like the ajax request not to be sent until the user has typed at least 3 characters, or even better, when they have typed characters and no matches are found in the initial options.

How can i control when the ajax request is sent?

Comment: btw, I tried minimumInputLength: 3, - but whilst it prevents an ajax request until 3 chars is typed, it doesn't show the itital options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can find an example of what you are looking for 
http://jsfiddle.net/tw57m8bx/1/

    function(options) {
        if (options.term) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/echo/json/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify(AJAX_OPTIONS),
                    delay: 0.3
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend and adapter and use it to achieve whhat u require,
this is more efficient and will allow you to load default options also

https://gist.github.com/govorov/274a8aac5fb910472ff1d0022f32f53e